# Angular-Material:- Template error for mat-radio-button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working with Angular material and faced one error with   although it works fine on stackblitz but not on my code. Below is the error which I am facing
I have imported MatRadioModule too.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group[ERROR ->]"): ng:///AppModule/RadioButtonsComponent.html@18:19
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._preparseLoadedTemplate (compiler.js:3220)
    at eval (compiler.js:3200)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._preParseTemplate (compiler.js:3200)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.js:3178)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14908)
    at eval (compiler.js:34412)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (compiler.js:34411)
```

and below is my HTML code

```
<mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: I have used only html do you need package.json?

Comment: The whole html file

Comment: thats all I have.Its a new html page

Comment: This error could stem from other components / html files that embed your component with the mat radio button. You have to check all the components up line to your index.html for html syntax errors.

Comment: can you show the imported module? whole code where you imported radiomodule. And if it is not appmodule paste app module too

Answer (score 1):

Just check the respective (your-module-name).module.ts file, whether you have imported "MatRadioModule" or not.